# Not able to import PyDIP module in python 3.7.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, diplib

I am new to python and machine vision, I installed `PyDIP` using `pip` in command **terminal** but now while importing the module in python version **3.7.5** it is showing no such module exist.

In python I am typing

```
import PyDIP
```

Please help , thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you typing the code? IDLE? Pycharm? Jupyter?

Comment: Try installing it with `pip3` (not `pip`)

Comment: Hey Kris it's IDLE

Comment: Hey ForceBru I tried with pip3 but then also while importing it;s showing no such module exists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyDIP', although it's installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59952057/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pydip-although-its-installed)

Comment: In particular, currently you need to install PyDIP from the available binary distribution (Windows) or from sources (Mac, Linux). https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/releases